# Drawing a square at mouse position using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

**What I expect:**

I created an area in my HTML page that takes up the entire width and height of the screen. What I am expecting is that a square is drawn at the position I click in my browser window.

This is my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <div class="canvas" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></div>

    <script src="../app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the JavaScript code I have written so far:

```
const d3 = require("d3");

const svg = d3.select(".canvas").append("svg").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 500);

d3.select(".canvas").on("click", function () {
  const mouseX = d3.mouse(this)[0];
  const mouseY = d3.mouse(this)[1];
  console.log(`Mouse X-position: ${mouseX}`);
  console.log(`Mouse Y-position: ${mouseY}`);

  drawSquare(mouseX, mouseY);
});

function drawSquare(mouseX, mouseY) {
  svg.append("rect").attr("x", mouseX).attr("y", mouseY).attr("width", 200).attr("height", 100);
}
```

It seems to be going wrong at this point:

```
const svg = d3.select(".canvas").append("svg").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 500);
```

I have no idea how I can get the elements width and height property set as the values to use. Not setting the attributes makes it so I can only use the uppler left corner of the area.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate: while I was writing the answer you edited your question, asking a *different* thing. I had no alternative except deleting my answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks for taking a look. I realized after posting that I did not look at that yet and edited the post as I found out that is where the problem lies. If you could give any input please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I can get a hold of the div's width and height as follows:

```
const parentDiv = document.getElementById("canvas");
const svg = d3.select(".canvas").append("svg").attr("width", parentDiv.clientWidth).attr("height", parentDiv.clientHeight);
```